# python map function with min argument and two lists

Tags: python

Im having trouble figuring out why this map function is producing the output it's producing. The code is as follows:

```
    L1 = [1, 28, 36]
    L2 = [2, 57, 9]
    print map(min, L1, L2)
```

output is:
        [1, 28, 9]

I understand it took the min values from the first list, but why did it not take the 2 from the second, and instead took the 9. Appreciate any feedback, thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to get `[1, 2]` as the result? If not, what do you require?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is made up from

```
[min(L1[0], L2[0]), min(L1[1], L2[1]), min(L1[2], L2[2])]
```

so `min` is being called on each pair of values to construct the new list

Answer (score 4):

`map(min, L1, L2)` means roughly this:

```
[min(L1[0], L2[0]), min(L1[1], L2[1]), min(L1[2], L2[2])]
```

So the min of [1,2] (first element of each list) is 1, min of [28,57] is 28, and min of [36,9] is 9.

You probably wanted `map(min, [L1, L2])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
map(min, L1, L2)
```

compares each elements of the two lists with **the same index**.

Thus,
It performs:

```
list = []
list.append(min(1,2)) #1
list.append(min(28,57)) #28
list.append(min(36,9)) #9
print list
```

leading to the output `[1, 28, 9]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at [the document](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map):

> `map(function, iterable, ...)`
>
> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable,
>   yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed,
>   function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items
>   from all iterables **in parallel**. ...

Here, **in parallel** means items of same index from different `iterable` are passed to `function` for each index.